# product images are not displayed web of prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am new in this world of prestashop, I mhave the following problem: I do not understand why from one moment to another the images of the products that I had registered on the page are not displayed.

Prestashop version 1.7.4.2

The tests that I have carried out according to what I have read on the internet and they have not worked for me are the following:

1. Main Menu > Personalize > Layout > Image Adjustment > Regenerate Images. Clear cache.
2. Disable friendly URLs, then I accessed my hosting, save a copy of the .htaccess file and then delete it from the server. I re-enabled friendly URLs and cleared the cache.

page url: https://www.liveloverockon.com/

[image]

the strange thing is that from the backoffice of the page, when editing a product if the images are seen.

[image]

I would really appreciate your help.
Greetings.

Comment: Your website seems down. This problem may cause of htaccess file. remove it and test again

Comment: Hi @MahdiShad, Thank you for your answer, this's link the website. https://liveloverockon.com/

Comment: https://check-host.net/check-report/be95521k2ac